# How hide right click menu in title bar? And how is called?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

How hide right click menu in title bar?

And how is called?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How hide right click menu in title bar? And how is called?

You could not hide title bar right click menu for uwp apps, it is by design and system level.